# Can't delete folder with desktop.ini folder inside it

Tags: windows-10

I have a `D:/folder` folder and I can't delete it.

The folder is apparently empty. However, when I try to delete it from Windows 10, nothing happens, no error, but folder doesn't disappear.

From the command line, I use the `dir /a` command and I can see that there is a `desktop.ini` folder (not file) with date `17/11/8725` inside my undeletable folder.

However, I cannot remove it with `rd desktop.ini`, nor can I open it (`dir desktop.ini`).

My disk is NTFS.

Other information:

- I was able to rename the folder and move it to a parent directory, this is, from `D:/something/something/initialfolder` to `D:/folder`.
- When I try to delete it from cmd the error message is `The directory name is invalid.`
- When I try to dir it from cd the error message is:

> Volume in Drive D is (drive name)
>
> Volume Serial Number is (serialnumber)
>
> Directory of D:\folder\desktop.ini
>
> File Not Found

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Checkdisk utility finds no error on the disk.

Comment: Are you able to change the name of the folder to something else? The behavior you describe suggests the folder/file is orphaned.

Comment: "I cannot remove it with rd desktop.ini" - what happens when you try?

Comment: So you have moved it and are still unable to remove the file?  Are you able to remove the file from within WSL2?  Instead of submitting temporary comments, that will be reported as "no longer being required", you should edit your question.

Comment: I have added the requested information to the original post.

Comment: What about the WSL2 suggestion?

Comment: @Ramhound Reading about it, first time I hear about it ;-)

Comment: Thank you for providing the missing error message to tell us what happens when you try to remove desktop.ini. But you still don't say what this bit means: "nor can I open it (dir desktop.ini)". What happens when you try?

Comment: @RegEdit File Not Found, also added.

Comment: ok but that's not an error, that's the normal message for an empty directory. Or a directory containing only hidden files. To show any files that have the `hidden` attribute set, repeat your `dir` command but add a space followed by `/ah`.

Comment: @RegEdit Anyway, "dir D:\folder\desktopicni /ah" returns File Not Found.

Comment: No hidden files in that folder then. It is a very strange problem. If you find the explanation, please do post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hard disk drive seems to be phisically faulty. Finally I bought a new HDD and I could copy all folders but that ghostly "desktop.ini" folder.

Answer (score 0):

To me this is suspicious and suggests malware.

The invalid year in the date is a sure sign that something abnormal has occurred. Since your disk check is normal, you should run a Windows Defender scan of your computer.

If Windows Defender doesn't find anything, do another full scan using the free [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) edition.

Comment: Both Windows Defender and Malwarebytes are ok, they don't find anything suspicious.